# Twilio Studio Function Parameter

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I am trying to pass a parameter to a function in a flow using Twilio Studio.  I can add the parameter no problem to the function widget, but how do I retrieve the parameter in the function?

Studio Screenshot

[image]

I've tried looking at the logs and can't figure out how to reference the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are properties of the `event` object, you can access with the dot notation. In your case something like this:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    const test = event.Test; 

    // your function code here...


};
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it would be something simple that I kept overlooking.